# MySQL - Generate sequence number for a grouping

Tags: mysql

I have been supplied with a source file for populating a MySQL database.
I have used a Python script to cleanse and transform data. A small example of the problem that I am trying to address is illustrated below.

**Source file**

```
Area                        | Team    |
---------------------------------------
NORTH EAST - CO.DURHAM BL   | Winters |
NORTH EAST - NEWCASTLE GT   | Summers |
......                                |
SOUTH EAST - SOUTHAMPTON BI | Winters |
```

**Stage 2 Transformed into DB staging table after cleansing etc.**

```
ID | Region     | City        | State     | Team    |
----------------------------------------------------|
1  | NORTH EAST | DURHAM      | BL        | Winters |
2  | NORTH EAST | NEWCASTLE   | GT        | Summers |
......                
80 | SOUTH EAST | SOUTHAMPTON | BI        | Winters |
```

**Stage 3 - Generate region ID for each Region grouping**

```
ID | Region ID  | Region     | City        | State     | Team    |
-------------------------------------------|-----------|---------|
1  | 1          | NORTH EAST | DURHAM      | BL        | Winters |
2  | 1          | NORTH EAST | NEWCASTLE   | GT        | Summers |
......                
80 | 10         | SOUTH EAST | SOUTHAMPTON | BI        | Winters |
```

Is it possible to generate a sequence number for a grouping in mysql? For example, in the scenario above is it possible to generate the `RegionID` column so that NORTH EAST region groupings are 1, SOUTH EAST groupings are 10 etc. How would this be achieved?

N.B Is there a way to generate the sequence automatically? For example could the values in the region id column automatically be generated without have to specify the ids manually in a region table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of the `DENSE_RANK` function. The sql snippet code below will generate a region id dynamically.

```sql
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Region) as RegionID,
    Region 
FROM StagingTable
ORDER BY Region
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE regions (
  region_id INT PRIMARY KEY
  region varchar(10),
  key(region)
);

INSERT INTO regions VALUES
(1, 'NORTH EAST'), (10,'SOUTH EAST'), etc...

UPDATE db_staging_table AS d
JOIN regions AS r USING (region)
SET d.region_id = r.region_id;
```

---

If you are using MySQL 8.0 you can do this:

```
WITH cte (region, region_id) AS (
  SELECT region, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() 
  FROM db_staging_table 
  GROUP BY region
)
UPDATE db_staging_table AS d JOIN cte ON d.region = cte.region 
SET d.region_id = cte.region_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that achieves what I want with the region id manually specified. Is there a way to generate the region id column automatically without have to specify the ids manually in the region table? Will update question....

Comment: Yes, you can create regions automatically with `create table regions (id serial, region varchar(10)); insert into regions (region) select distinct region from stgtbl;`